# Не сразу отображаются items в recyclerView, но только после первой смены конфигурации (поворота экрана)

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, dialogfragment

Коллеги проблема такая - в recyclerview внутри DialogFragment элементы отображаются не сразу, а сначала открывается пустой и только после первого поворота экрана - заполненный. Причину не могу понять.
Буду благодарен если кто-то сможет подсказать куда копать.
(LOGS в onCreateDialog с первого раза показывает что customView не null, а уже присвоен лаяут.)
Код:

ДиалогФрагмент:

```
class ChooseCategoryDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), ChooseCategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private val viewModel: EditTransactionViewModel by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })
    private var _binding: FragmentDialogRecyclerBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = FragmentDialogRecyclerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.choose_category))
            .setView(binding.root)
            .setNegativeButton(requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.cancel_action), null)
            .create()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val category = viewModel.spendCategoryName.value
        val chooseCatAdapter = ChooseCategoryAdapter(this, category)

        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.apply {
                viewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    chooseCatAdapter.submitList(it)
                }
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                adapter = chooseCatAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Адаптер:

```
class ChooseCategoryAdapter(
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener,
    private val curCatName: String?
) : ListAdapter<Category, ChooseCategoryAdapter.ChooseCatViewHolder>(ChooseCatComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChooseCatViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemDialogRecyclerBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ChooseCatViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChooseCatViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(curItem)
    }

    inner class ChooseCatViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDialogRecyclerBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val category = getItem(position)
                        listener.onItemClick(category)
                    }
                }
                radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val category = getItem(position)
                        listener.onItemClick(category)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(category: Category) {
            binding.apply {
                tvCatname.text = category.catName
                radioButton.isChecked = category.catName == curCatName
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(category: Category)
    }

    class ChooseCatComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Category>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Category, newItem: Category) =
            oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Category, newItem: Category) =
            oldItem.catName == newItem.catName
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь попробовал перенести весь код кроме последних двух строчек метода onCreateView в метод onViewCreated

Comment: Скорее всего к моменту первого отображения списка данные еще не поступили в адаптер

Comment: А почему может быть такое что данные не успевают поступить в адаптер? Все еще не нашел решение.

Comment: А откуда поступают данные, интернет, бд?

Comment: из Room database

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобным: у меня был просто текст, в процессе он добавлялся и не был виден, а после поворота появлялся. Оказалось что диалог помещает контент в скроллер и задаёт ему размер по изначальному содержимому. Когда контент меняется диалог не пересчитывает размеры вью и контента не видно, но он прокручивается в малюсеньком фрейме. Варианты: изначально  задать размеры вью/диалога, а лучше сначала получить данные, а потом показывать диалог, когда всё готово.

Comment: "а лучше сначала получить данные, а потом показывать диалог, когда всё готово" - хм. А как это сделать, если onCreateDialog раотает раньше, чем я могу запустить viewLifeCyclerOwner который наблюдает ЛивДату? (Сам диагноз очень похож на правду, поскольку список сразу НЕ пустой, просто его именно что не видно. Плюс когда я делаю все идентично в обычном Фрагменте - все сразу отображается, только в Диалоге проблема.)

Comment: Я не знаю какая у вас логика и архитектура приложения, по существу не подскажу. Я имею ввиду, что данные неплохо было бы получить вне этого фрагмента вообще, а показать его уже по факту получения данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally спустя 2 недели я нашел ответ: надо было удалить строку `setHasFixedSize(true)`, потому что она мешала окну диалогФрагмента подогнать размер под приходящие данные.